# codeigniter, how to select database join three tables

Tags: codeigniter, activerecord, mysqli

[image: structure three tables]

[image]

[image]
[image]

```
ask how to select customer.no_member,customer.name,SUM sale_item.harga ,sale.tgl_transaksi where status =selesai group_by customer.name join sale.id = sale_item.sale_id join sale.customer = customer.name
```

Comment: Wow! can you actually be bothered to type in anything here?! No problem description, no context. Good luck not getting downvoted. Take the tour and read the reference sites!! Check the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: show ur code what u have tried?

Answer (score 0):

I know the structure of your table is not good. There is another table there, that is item, right? and you need to give id_cs column in your sale_item table.

But I try to give you an example to join 4 table. I hope it will solve your problem.

```
$this->db->select(cs.*, si.*, sale.*, i.*);
$this->db->from('sale_item si');
$this->db->join('customer cs', 'si.cs_id = cs.id');
$this->db->join('sale', 'si.sale_id = sale.id');
$this->db->join('item i', 'si.item_id = i.id');
```

Comment: thak's you for your question

Comment: I just try to answer your question sir. if it's solve your problem, just give it a tick.